# how can i get the details of my current product.id in my browser url using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to display {{product.title}} in my browser url , please how can i go about it

this is my json object

```
{
    "status": true,
    "product": {
        "_id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e",
        "title": "galaxy note",
        "description": "Lorem ",
    }
}
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      product: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${this.$route.params.id}`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

this is my route

```
  {path: "/products/:id", name: "Product", component: Product},
```

this is how i go to the id route

```
 <router-link :to="`/products/${product._id}`">
          <img
            :src="product.photo"
            alt="Placeholder image"
          >
        </router-link>
```

by default it displays http://localhost:8080/products/625672a8370e769a8a93a51e in my url how can i get it to display http://localhost:8080/products/galaxy-note

Comment: how do you redirect to this page? please show that code. I guess you are passing ID in the url thats why it's showing you ID. Instead of ID, pass the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said you are passing `id` while redirecting the page. You need pass `title` key in the `<router-link>` tag.

```js
{path: "/products/:title", name: "Product", component: Product}
```

---

```js
<router-link :to="`/products/${product.title}`">
   <img
     :src="product.photo"
     alt="Placeholder image"
   >
</router-link>
```

With this done, you will have this URL `http://localhost:8080/products/galaxy-note`.

Make sure that whatever value you get in the `title` key of the `product` object, that will be appended in the URL.

Next thing to take care is when you call the API using axios in the `mounted` hook in your script tag. You won't get `id` in params. You will get the `title` in the params object, therefore you need to update that code as well.

**EDIT 1:** If you are receiving value with spaces such as *galaxy note* and you want to have *galaxy-note* in the url then you might need to replace `spaces` with the `-` using replace function before passing it to the `<router-link>` tag.

Comment: i don't know why i get %20  in my route
  http://localhost:8080/products/galaxy%20note

Comment: That is because you have space between galaxy and note. Browser automatically converts spaces into %20. You need to replace space with a dash or need to get value with a dash from back-end (in case if you getting this value via API), for an instance “galaxy-note”.